# Sum Excel columns

Tags: vba, excel

I need to make a loop, for each Code I must have only one row
[image]

Here I share with you more details of the formula
[image]

Comment: You can use excels, `subtotal` function to achieve what you are looking for

Comment: so you wont actually need any code. However, if you can elaborate your requirement, it can be clearer as to why you need the loop

Comment: I have 8000 rows thats why i need the loop,
I don't inderstand the `subtotal`
I put this formula `=SOUS.TOTAL(9;B2:B21;A2:A21)`

Comment: it will work, Just make sure to order your data by column A

Comment: or atlist, have you tried it?

Comment: just google, the excel subtotal

Comment: I dont inderstunt how to use it

Comment: lol, so first order your sheet by column A, then click subtotal. Set `at each change in` to column A. `Use function` set to sum, And click on on the column you want to sum

Comment: I google it i make this [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba9Ul.png) but i cant see the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this excel function:

[image]

Then click within your table and click on subtotal. The below window will display. Then set the criteria as you want.

[image]